# Creation of a n-ary tree through level based tree traversal of another

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

So i am traversing level-wise an n-ary tree having nodes with attributes id and name, i want to alter the name of each node and create another similar n-ary tree with the altered nodes (the root node having `A` as `id`)

```
    Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    // node being the root node of the already created n-ary tree
    queue.add(node);
    Node rootOut = new Node(node.id,node.name);
    Node copiedNode = null;
    Node resNode = null;
    // iterate while queue not empty
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){

        // dequeue
        Node next = queue.remove();
    
 
        
        copiedNode = new Node(next.id,next.name);
        for (Node child : next.children) {
           

            Node copiedChildNode = new Node(child.id,child.name);
            copiedNode.children.add(copiedChildNode);
            if (next.id == "A") rootOut = copiedNode;
            queue.add(child);
        }
    }
    return rootOut ;
```

But this doesn't return the root node of a correct new tree. In fact this returns just the root node and its immediate children but no further depth. Could anybody help to do that properly

Comment: What do you expect to see with some example inputs? For example, if you had a tree `B -> A -> C -> D` what do you expect the output to be? Just `A -> C -> D` or should `B` be in there somewhere and, if so, where?

Comment: I expect to get `  A-> B-> C -> D` with each node having an altered name in comparison with the original tree (the order is unchanged)

Comment: But the bottom line is you're not copying the tree properly. Each iteration you're copying the current element and its children but never keeping track of the copies you make. You probably want a depth-first traversal. If you must use a level-based traversal, you need a second structure to store your copy.

Comment: Is it `A -> B -> C -> D` because you renamed `A` and `B`? I.e., their IDs are the same as they were before? Or because you swapped them fully? Where is your code that does the swap?

Comment: it is in that order because the level order traversal of the first tree is in that order, now i rename a property of each node which is not visible in your example

Comment: The second structure i use is the root node `rootOut ` which starts as a copy of the root node of the first original tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is not tracking the copies you're making, so you're not building a tree, just a bunch of single-node copies and their children:

```
    queue.add(node);
    Node copiedNode = null;

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        Node next = queue.remove();

        // A new copy (not being referenced by anything)
        copiedNode = new Node(next.id,next.name);
        for (Node child : next.children) {
           

            // A new copy (referenced by only the aforementioned copy
            Node copiedChildNode = new Node(child.id,child.name);
            copiedNode.children.add(copiedChildNode);

            // If the original was "A", store a reference to the copy.
            if (next.id == "A") rootOut = copiedNode;

            // The original is queued, not the copy
            queue.add(child);
        }
    }
 
    // Return only the shallow copy
    return rootOut ;
```

You need to build a structure in the copy, tracking the references:

```
    Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(node);
    Node rootOut = new Node(node.id,node.name);

    // For tracking copies
    Map<String, Node> copiedNodesById = new HashMap<>();
    copiedNodesById.put(rootOut.id, rootOut);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){

        Node currentOriginal = queue.remove();
        // Get an existing copy rather than making a new one.
        Node currentCopy = copiedNodesById.get(currentOriginal.id);
        
        for (Node childOriginal : currentOriginal.children) {

            Node copiedChildNode = new Node(childOriginal.id,childOriginal.name);
            currentCopy.children.add(copiedChildNode);

            // Track the copy that was just made.
            copiedNodesById.put(copiedChildNode.id, copiedChildNode);
            
            if (next.id == "A") rootOut = currentCopy;
            queue.add(childOriginal);
        }
    }
    return rootOut ;
```

I took the liberty of renaming some variables to make it clearer what is original vs a copy.

The copied nodes could have also been tracked in another queue as well. Or the queue could track (original, copy) tuples instead.

As for restructuring the copy based on the location of "A", I'll leave that to you since it's unclear to me how that is supposed to function.

Comment: Does `rootOut ` now contain the new tree ? `A` being the name of root node of the original tree

Comment: Not the way you've specified it (no `A <-> B` swapping) but it will contain `A`'s grandchildren unlike your attempt.

Comment: no sorry again i need to add the root `A` to the rootOut node, it is starting from `B`

Comment: You could simply swap their names, or perhaps swap their names and their children. I'm still unsure of what exactly it is that you need, however the solution I've provided should get you started as at least the structure is now being copied.